# Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <g:select>

Tags: jsp, grails, tomcat7

I just put the new version on the production server, I get the the following exception when I want to create a new authorization for an user.

> Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag : Error executing tag : null at /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/authorization /create.gsp:31 at /WEB-INF/grails-app/views/authorization /create.gsp:53

I tested on localhost, it works without problems and on the test server also no problem.
This error is in a jsp page, the tag select used to load the list of users.

**Controller**

```
def create = {

    def authorization Instance = new Authorization ()
    authorizationInstance.properties = params
    users=listusers.getAllwithoutAdmin()
    return [authorizationInstance: authorizationInstance,users:users]
}
```

**Create.jsp**

```
<fieldset>
                <dl>
                <dt><label for="user"><g:message code="authorization.user.label" default="User" /></label></dt>
                <dd><g:select name="user.id" from="${users}" optionValue="${it.name}" optionKey="id"  Value="${authorizationInstance?.user?.id}" /></dd>
                </dl>
```

I try to understand why i get this error.

Is that-because there is already the old version of this application works on the server?

**P.S:** : I use the 1.3.7 grails version

Comment: You are going to need to include the gsp and perhaps even the controller code that backs that GSP. Otherwise it's going to be impossible for anyone to identify what the problem is. You may want to include what version of Grails you are using as well.

Comment: It solved ;), I rebooted the old and the new version of application on the server, the error is disappeared